# Take multiple string variables and solve as arithmetic in Swift 2

Tags: swift2

I would like to take the following variables and solve them.

```
var a = "3"
var b = "6"
var c = "9"

let mult="*"
let lPar = "("
let rPar = ")"
```

I want to throw that together to something along the lines of 
(a),(lPar),(b),(mult),(c),(rPar) and get 3(6*9) solved.

Do I use NSExpression for this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I am just starting out.  I actually don't know what to use.  I saw similar examples using NSExpression, but to no avail on my end.  So I thought maybe I am heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO :)  You can check out [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get started on the right foot! Enjoy your Swift journey!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use NSExpression to perform simple arithmetics:

```
var expression = "$A * ( $B + $C )"
var variables:NSMutableDictionary = ["A":3, "B":6, "C":9]
let result = NSExpression(format:expression).expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: variables) 
// result = 45
```